# iOS. Send push to devices which are offline

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to send push notification to app users. Users whom online will receive it immediately, right?. But what about users whom offline? Will they get notification after they become online?

Can you tell me more about than push notifications will de delivered?

Are messengers use pushes to send notifications about new messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible in offline.

Check it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

> Apple Push Notification Service includes a default Quality of Service (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline, the QoS stores the notification. It retains only one notification per application on a device: the last notification received from a provider for that application. When the offline device later reconnects, the QoS forwards the stored notification to the device. The QoS retains a notification for a limited period before deleting it.
>
> If a device remains offline for a long time, all notifications that were being stored for it are discarded; when the device goes back online, none of the notifications are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Apple will try to deliver the notification when the device will become online again (in a resonable time frame).

> Apple Push Notification service includes a default Quality of Service (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs attempts to deliver a notification but the destination device is offline, APNs stores the notification for a limited period of time and delivers it to the device when the device becomes available.

From https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9